# Are there GPG-signed OpenBSD ISOs with which I can verify an installation disc?

Tags: security, system-installation, openbsd

Are there GPG-signed OpenBSD ISOs that I can download and later verify the downloaded file? Or at least a GPG-signed [shasum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum)?

Answer (score 3):

From the [OpenBSD FAQ pages](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq3.html#ISO):

> The OpenBSD project does not digitally sign releases. [...] If the men
>   in black suits are out to get you, they're going to get you.

However, Theo de Raadt (the OpenBSD founder) [has announced earlier this year](http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=138992613426488&w=2) that the project is moving towards signed packages. Hopefully, this will include signing whole release discs.

Comment: See my answer below for info on verifying a complete ISO for OpenBSD 6.4.

Answer (score 1):

Open BSD releases are not signed using PGP keys. Instead the project uses a [custom built tool called signify](https://www.openbsd.org/papers/bsdcan-signify.html)
to sign releases.

**But how do users determine the correct key without something like the PGP web of trust?**

On Oct 24th, 2018 I met with 2 OpenBSD devs in person to verify the current release key.  The message below was signed by Theo Bühler `<tb[AT]openbsd.org>` (PGP: `0x582F9C0EAA32139A`) and the key you see was also verified visually letter by letter by Reyk Flöter `<reyk[AT]openbsd.org>` (PGP: `0x1A12678032292F9D`).

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

untrusted comment: openbsd 6.4 base public key
RWQq6XmS4eDAcQW4KsT5Ka0KwTQp2JMOP9V/DR4HTVOL5Bc0D7LeuPwA
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=irX3
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

I also verified Theo Bühler's PGP key and ID and we signed each other's keys so that there would be a PGP "Web Of Trust" path to his key.

Once you have the correct key, you can use [these instructions to verify an an iso](https://github.com/jonathancross/jc-docs/blob/master/pgp/OpenBSD_verification.md) using the `signify` tool.